# Why do I get error 'iCloud Keychain is disabled'?

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase

I implement Firebase Auth in Xcode , when I try app and register 
error message has been shown "iCloud Keychain is disabled"

how I can solve it please ?

> 2019-05-27 13:22:01.286422+0300 OPTION 1[1629:161800] [AutoFill]
>   Cannot show Automatic Strong Passwords for app bundleID:
>   com.qaysi.OPTION1 due to error: iCloud Keychain is disabled

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Enable iCloud Keychain on iPhone and iPad:

1. Launch the Settings app on your iPhone or iPad.
2. Tap your Apple ID banner.
3. Tap iCloud.
4. Scroll down and tap Keychain.
5. Toggle the iCloud Keychain switch on.
6. Enter your Apple ID password if prompted.

Now in your project, enable Keychain sharing for the target that you are working on. In your Xcode:

1. Open project setting.
2. Open capabilities tab.
3. Enable keychain sharing.

[image: xCodeEnableKeySharing]